# Remove padding for first and last column in row

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have a situation where the grid can't have an outside left and right padding.

How to set padding-left:0; for first column in line and set padding-right:0. This should also when screen changes... Or make similar result.

```
<div class="row line">
  <div class="large-2 medium-3 small-4 columns"></div>
  <div class="large-2 medium-3 small-4 columns"></div>
  <div class="large-2 medium-3 small-4 columns"></div>
  <div class="large-2 medium-3 small-4 columns"></div>
</div>
```

1. line for large screen
2. line for medium screen
3. line for small screen

Yellow space should be with no padding, white spaces has default foundation padding.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to target the first and last columns.

```
.row.line > .columns:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.row.line > .columns:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Another option would be to create a class to apply to the first and last columns.

```
<div class="row line">
  <div class="large-2 medium-3 small-2 columns column-first"></div>
  <div class="large-2 medium-3 small-2 columns"></div>
  <div class="large-2 medium-3 small-2 columns"></div>
  <div class="large-2 medium-3 small-2 columns column-last"></div>
</div>

.column-first {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.column-last {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by nesting another .row inside of your .row. When you do this, you get something like:

```
.row .row {
width: auto;
margin-left: -0.9375rem; 
margin-right: -0.9375rem;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: but by default columns has padding from both sides and padding appears anyway